# Python Selenium NewConnectionIssue Windows 11

Tags: python, windows, selenium

I'm using Python, Selenium and ChromeDriver to perform web automations. I'm experiencing `NewConnectionError`s since moving to Windows 11.

Code below, where `DRIVER_URL` and `SESSIONS_ID` are printed in the first iteration to *address* the Chrome browser.

```py
# Your path, and previously printed strings
CHROME_DRIVER_PATH = 'your/path'
DRIVER_URL = 'something_previously_printed_out'
SESSION_ID = 'something_previously_printed_out'

# Setting Chrome options
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.headless = False
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

# If strings are determined then perform a Remote connection
if DRIVER_URL != '' or SESSION_ID != '':
    driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor=DRIVER_URL, desired_capabilities={})
    driver.session_id = SESSION_ID
# If strings are not determined, then open new browser and print address strings
else:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(CHROME_DRIVER_PATH, options=chrome_options)
    print(driver.command_executor._url)
    print(driver.session_id)
```

The error is

```bash
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=56130): Max retries exceeded with url: /session (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001420063EE60>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))
```

I did not have this issue in Windows 10. It appears to be a Firewall issue on the port in `dirver.command_executor._url`. I disabled the Firewall in my settings, though this did not work.

What must I do to resolve the issue?

Thank you.

Comment: your code throws an error at `driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor=DRIVER_URL, desired_capabilities={})` , few thinks to check: 1. i hope you don't have limits on DRIVER_URL 2. server is refusing the connection, was there any IP or device whitelisting?

Comment: Thank you for helping, @simpleApp. I haven't set any limits, and I'm not aware what they may be *on*. May you elaborate so I may check? I haven't performed any IP whitelisting. This is connecting to `localhost:port`. Thanks again.

Comment: error is this one `No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it`, i think your python and selenium versions would have changed during the transition, would you pls refer to this [official source](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/drivers/remote_webdriver/) and try to adjust the code? sorry i can't reproduce this as don't have access or detail about what this does `host='localhost', port=56130`